# Merging two XML files with XSLT 3.0

Tags: xml, merge, xslt-3.0

I would like to use the xsl:merge instruction introduced in XSLT 3.0:
[https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#merging]

Following the example 'Merging Several Documents with the Same Structure', I can merge two lists on one key, but I am having trouble trying to do so on two nested keys.

Here are my two test XML files:

```
<list>
   <item id="1">
      <descr ref="a"/>
      <descr ref="b"/>
   </item>
   <item id="2">
      <descr ref="c"/>
      <descr ref="d"/>
   </item>
   <item id="3">
      <descr ref="e">one</descr>
      <descr ref="f">one</descr>
   </item>
</list>
```

and:

```
<list>
   <item id="3">
      <descr ref="e">two</descr>
      <descr ref="f">two</descr>
      <descr ref="x">two</descr>
   </item>
   <item id="4">
      <descr ref="z"/>
      <descr ref="y"/>
   </item>
</list>
```

And here is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.1">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
   <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <list>
         <xsl:merge>
            <xsl:merge-source name="master" for-each-source="'list1.xml'" sort-before-merge="yes" select="/list/item">
               <xsl:merge-key select="@id" order="ascending"/>
            </xsl:merge-source>
            <xsl:merge-source name="update" for-each-source="'list2.xml'" sort-before-merge="yes" select="/list/item">
               <xsl:merge-key select="@id" order="ascending"/>
            </xsl:merge-source>
            <xsl:merge-action>
               <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="empty(current-merge-group('update'))">
                     <xsl:copy-of select="current-merge-group('master')"/>
                     <xsl:message>master!</xsl:message>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="empty(current-merge-group('master'))">
                     <xsl:copy-of select="current-merge-group('update')"/>
                     <xsl:message>update!</xsl:message>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                     <item>
                        <xsl:merge>
                           <xsl:merge-source name="descr-master" sort-before-merge="yes" select="descr">
                              <xsl:merge-key select="@ref" order="ascending"/>
                           </xsl:merge-source>
                           <xsl:merge-source name="descr-update" sort-before-merge="yes" select="descr">
                              <xsl:merge-key select="@ref" order="ascending"/>
                           </xsl:merge-source>
                           <xsl:merge-action>
                              <xsl:choose>
                                 <xsl:when test="empty(current-merge-group('descr-update'))">
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-merge-group('descr-master')"/>
                                    <xsl:message>descr master!</xsl:message>
                                 </xsl:when>
                                 <xsl:when test="empty(current-merge-group('descr-master'))">
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-merge-group('descr-update')"/>
                                    <xsl:message>descr update!</xsl:message>
                                 </xsl:when>
                                 <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-merge-group('descr-update')"/>
                                    <xsl:message>present in both: kept update!</xsl:message>
                                 </xsl:otherwise>
                              </xsl:choose>
                           </xsl:merge-action>
                        </xsl:merge>
                     </item>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
               </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:merge-action>
         </xsl:merge>
      </list>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is correct when an item is present in just one of the two lists, but not in both.
What's wrong?

What I am trying to achieve would be this list:

```
<list>
   <item id="1">
      <descr ref="a"/>
      <descr ref="b"/>
   </item>
   <item id="2">
      <descr ref="c"/>
      <descr ref="d"/>
   </item>
   <item id="3">
      <descr ref="e">two</descr>
      <descr ref="f">two</descr>
      <descr ref="x">two</descr>
   </item>
   <item id="4">
      <descr ref="z"/>
      <descr ref="y"/>
   </item>
</list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pick up the data from the outer merge groups:

```
             <xsl:otherwise>
                 <item>
                    <xsl:merge>
                       <xsl:merge-source name="descr-master" sort-before-merge="yes" select="current-merge-group('master')/descr">
                          <xsl:merge-key select="@ref" order="ascending"/>
                       </xsl:merge-source>
                       <xsl:merge-source name="descr-update" sort-before-merge="yes" select="current-merge-group('update')/descr">
                          <xsl:merge-key select="@ref" order="ascending"/>
                       </xsl:merge-source>
                       <xsl:merge-action>
                          <xsl:choose>
                             <xsl:when test="empty(current-merge-group('descr-update'))">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="current-merge-group('descr-master')"/>
                                <xsl:message>descr master!</xsl:message>
                             </xsl:when>
                             <xsl:when test="empty(current-merge-group('descr-master'))">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="current-merge-group('descr-update')"/>
                                <xsl:message>descr update!</xsl:message>
                             </xsl:when>
                             <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="current-merge-group('descr-update')"/>
                                <xsl:message>present in both: kept update!</xsl:message>
                             </xsl:otherwise>
                          </xsl:choose>
                       </xsl:merge-action>
                    </xsl:merge>
                 </item>
              </xsl:otherwise>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works!
Just to complete the solution, in order to copy the @id/item, this was missing:

```
             <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:merge>
```

Thanks a lot!